# li a: hover displacing other links

Tags: css, hover

The CSS solution for a anchor tag hover effect that I have implemented is displacing other list items within the list of navigation links.

I would like the other list items to stay in place.

```css
:root {
  --fs-600: 1rem;
  --fs-700: 1.25rem;
  --clr-accent-400: red;
}
.nav-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(169, 125, 169);
  font-size: var(--fs-600);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, font-size 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-list a:hover,
.nav-list a:focus {
  color: var(--clr-accent-400);
  font-size: var(--fs-700);
}
```

```html
<ul aria-label="Primary" role="list" class="nav-list">
  <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Reiki</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Appointments</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: then you need to give the elements a fixed width/height that is not calculated to fit the content. A larger font size will naturally enlarge an element. As side note, the semantic correct tag for a list of anchors is `menu` not `ul`

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to give the `li` a fixed height of `var(--fs-700)`. That way it has a height to fit the `font-size` during hover:

```css
/* added by editor for demo purpose */
:root {
  --fs-600: 1em;
  --fs-700: 1.5em;
}


/* original CSS */
.nav-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(169, 125, 169);
  font-size: var(--fs-600);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, font-size 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-list a:hover,
.nav-list a:focus {
  color: var(--clr-accent-400);
  font-size: var(--fs-700);
}


/* added CSS as solution */
.nav-list li {
  height: var(--fs-700);
}
```

```html
<menu aria-label="Primary" role="list" class="nav-list">
  <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Reiki</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Appointments</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
</menu>
```

Comment: That didn't work. However, it did put me on the right track. I amended my code as follows and this largely resolves it. There is still a little bit of push out on the li items either side of the anchor being interacted with with but it's much better:

.nav-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(169, 125, 169);
  font-size: var(--fs-600);
  line-height: var(--fs-700);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, font-size 0.3s ease-in-out;
}